# Significado y traduccion de "Dolor de pecho", o "duele el pecho"

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, modismos, expresiones, idiomático

Que significa en español la expresion "(le) duele el pecho"?

Ejemplo: "Al devoto le duele el pecho cuando su corazon sale a acariciar el infinito".

Como se traduce al ingles esta expresion, sin que suene muy torpe o equivocada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que esa frase no tiene ningún significado entre líneas, aunque obviamente la oración completa es un "sinsentido" en la vida real porque un corazón no puede salirse del pecho, etc., la frase `le duele el pecho` no me parece que necesite algún tipo de aclaración o traducción especial, si no, simplemente "His chest hurts" porque creo que en inglés y en español esa frase refleja melancolía. La oración completa si tiene una ligera variación, pero no creo que el significado del contexto se pierda  : 
*`The devotee's chest hurts when his heart goes out to caress the infinity.`*

Answer (score 0):

I would say something similar to this:

```
"The devoted has chest pain when his heart hangs to stroke the infinite"
```

---You can use or replace the word "hangs" with "goes out" or "relieve"

```
"The devoted has chest pain when his heart is relieve to stroke the infinite"

"The devoted has chest pain when his heart goes out to stroke the infinite"
```

Comment: .. or maybe  "his heart reaches (out) for infinity" would flow better.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases "heartache" is a better translation than "chest pain". It depends on context